# Retrieving data by value firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]Those Users who have b- bloodGroup i want to retreive their name ,age,contact etc...
I can search for b- users properly. But how to retreive the username, mobile etc of all the blood group users found to a listview or something like that?

```
 searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                searchBlood=search.getText().toString();
                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("bloodGroup").equalTo(searchBlood);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. What is the issue ?

Comment: In your `query` , what is searchBlood, String of what is written on search bar?

Comment: Please tell us  what do you expect this code to do? And what is it actually doing right now?

Comment: Your code is correct. Have you tried to print what is inside your `DataSnapshot` object? Please respond with @Name.

Comment: No issue i am searching correctly for the searched blood group.Now when the required blood is searched how to retreive the username,mobile etc of all the serached blood group users to a listview or something like that.@ Ahmed Abidi....@ Alex Mamo

Comment: yes that is string (Blood Group) that user will searched...i can get the total children count of searched blood but i want to retreive the username mobile etc of those users who have the searched blood...am i clear sir?@Code Nemesis